# CSS transform for parallax effect causing font aliasing issues in browser

Tags: css, css-transforms, antialiasing

Having an issue with a site that we are working with another dev team. They have created a parallax effect which makes use of CSS Transform effect as follows:

```
.content-wrapper {transform: translateX(5px) translateZ(92px) scale(.7);}
```

This is causing big issues with font rendering in the browsers - most obvious on Internet Explorer. I think it's of particular concern to PC users as other dev team who setup the CSS Parallax effect all use Macintosh computers.

I altered the css so it read like this `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)`and that definitely fixes the font issue but makes a mess of the parallax effect. How would i be able to keep the translate and scale values but get better font rendering?

Comment: Can you post a working fiddle ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. Too much work behind that. Was just hoping that another developer has come across the same issue. I'm beginning to think that this parallax technique is too advanced for current browsers to handle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cL495Lpu/  - Is this the issue you are facing? The text getting blurred?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it. Site has a few divs and the transform property, whilst being used for parallax, is making much of the text appear blurry in the web browsers. Much more noticeable in IE. Using transform: translate3d(0,0,0); fixes it up but throws out the whole parallax effect

Comment: Why don't you use parallax.js ?

Comment: Well, we did ended up going with a JS solution anyhow that injected the Transfrom property and the min-height into the DOM. Using a parent div container class of parallax. Just required more code.